# Best way to send data from multiple table of database from android to webservice

Tags: android, android-asynctask

im using the asynctask to send the data from one android sqlite table to a webservice using asynctask now im having multiple data about 5 table to send to the same webservice ..
My question is what is the best way to do that ..
Do i need to call the async task for each table OR make a different post request for each table  OR there is another way to do this ..

Comment: Or make a single POST call and let your webservice do the job with the database.

Comment: do you mean that its better to make a single post and send the data of the first table then the second then the third.....

Comment: I mean its better to make a json with all your data and send it in a single post call, while all that data is going to the same webservice of course.